# Auto scaling few Components at the same time

Tags: java, swing

Saying simply i am going to make a game with moving ball on the background from image and few obstacles. I would like also to have JPanel on the left side with few buttons. I made JSplitPane with ButtonPanel on the left side and i try to make the part with game on the right side of JSplitPane.

I would like to hava the
    part with game auto scaling both background and obstacles whenever i will change the size of window.
    (background, and obstacles are in diffrent classes which extends
    JPanel). 
How to make everything auto scaling together??

Please :) any help would be appreciated.

sorry for my english but it's not my native language, still learning ;-)

Comment: The basic answer is "yes", if it meets your needs.  Personally, unless you want to be able to expand/contact the UI (through the split pane), I'd probably just stick to a `BorderLayout` personally.  Collision detection can be done through a virtual concept, rather then relying on the physical object, but that will depend, do you only want to bound detection or pixel detection (where transparent pixels of the image don't create a collision)

Comment: *"I have couple of questions"*  Then you should probably have a couple of threads, in case someone can answer one question, but not the others.